# HTML Textboxes as data in tr. How do I perform dynamic search operation for such table on input of search string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-plugins

- Below is my html code. I fetch data from the database using `<sql:...>` and futher iterate using `<c:forEach ...>` and contain the data
  as value in textbox which is within `tr`.
- Now I want to perform dynamic search operation for such table. I
  tried some code using jquery, but it only seems to work when I add data to my
  tr directly like, `<tr>${row.barcode}</tr>`. The code does not work for `<td> <input type="text" value="${row.barcode}"> </td>`.

products.html

```
<html>
  <label for="search">Search products :</label>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter text to search">

  <!-- Fetch table data -->
   <sql:setDataSource var="myDataSource" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.56.49:1521:something" user="something" password="something"/>
   <sql:query var="result" sql="select * from garageproducts" dataSource="${myDataSource}"/>

        <table id="mytable">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Mark</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                      <tr>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox">                    </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" value="${row.barcode}"> </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" value="${row.name}">    </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" value="${row.brand}">   </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" value="${row.stock}">   </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" value="${row.cost}">    </td>
                      </tr>
                    </c:forEach>

                </tbody>
        </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially found a solution. The search is working but it does not work as expected. It **hides all the cells** which do not match the search string.

Following is the fiddle link for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/freecoder/hfhtga0g/6/

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#search").keyup(function() {
                _this = this;
                // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
                $.each($('#mytable tbody tr td>input[type="text"]'), function() {
                  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                    $(this).hide();
                  else
                    $(this).show();
                });
              });
            });

    </script>

    <html>
      <label for="search">Search products :</label>
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter text to search">

      <!-- Fetch table data -->
       <sql:setDataSource var="myDataSource" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.56.49:1521:something" user="something" password="something"/>
       <sql:query var="result" sql="select * from garageproducts" dataSource="${myDataSource}"/>

            <table id="mytable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Mark</th>
                        <th>Barcode</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                          <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox">                    </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.barcode}"> </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.name}">    </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.brand}">   </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.stock}">   </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="${row.cost}">    </td>
                          </tr>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
    </html>
```